# using angular router with queryParams

Tags: angular, parameters

Currently on angular v8 and using queryParams to make some network calls.

The problem is with the format of how the angular queryParams passes it to the route.

For example....

current URL:

> /inbox;name=123;tab=first

URL i want:

> /inbox?name=123&tab=first

Code i have currently:

```
  onClick(report) {
    if(report) {
      this.router.navigate(['/inbox', { name: this.id, tab: this.tab }]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Got to https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate. See that navigate takes an optional argument of type NavigationExtras. Click on this type to know what you can pass. Notice it has a queryParams member.

Comment: Also note this is covered in the router tutorial: [*"The optional route parameters are not separated by "?" and "&" as they would be in the URL query string. They are **separated by semicolons** ";" This is* matrix *URL notation..."*](https://angular.io/guide/router#heroes-list-optionally-selecting-a-hero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this, it is really easy to read and give you lots of good info..

https://alligator.io/angular/query-parameters/

Here is the first example:

```
goProducts() {
  this.router.navigate(['/products'], { queryParams: { order: 'popular' } });
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I know people downvoted your post, but dont be afraid to ask questions! but also dont be afraid to check google as well! Or other stack posts. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my navigation service i have this. It's a reusable function to navigate througth the app.

```
navigateTo(page: string, data?: any): Promise<void> {
      return this.router.navigate([page], {queryParams: data, skipLocationChange: true})
        .then(success => {
          if (!success) {
            console.error('navigation failed');
          }
        });
  }
```